# Loss of accuracy in orthogonalisation of polynomials using Orthogonalize

Tags: numerical-integration, polynomials, precision-and-accuracy

**Context**

As a mean to understand the growth of structure in the universe,
I am interested in characterising the curvature of random fields such as this one:

[image]

For this purpose I start with a PDF of the eigenvalues of the second derivative of the field (a measure of the local curvature). For a Gaussian Random Field this PDF reads

```
Pdf1= 2 Sqrt[2/π] (x1-x2) Exp[1/2 (-x1 (3 x1-x2)-x2 (3 x2-x1))]
```

and looks like this:

```
rg = {{x1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x2, -Infinity, x1}};
rgn = {{x1, -2, 2}, {x2, -2, x1}};
ContourPlot[Pdf1, Sequence @@ rgn // Evaluate,  ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

while when the field becomes non Gaussian (like the above),  the PDF can be quite different:

[image]

> My purpose is to use orthogonal polynomials to represent this Non Gaussian PDF.

**Attempt**

I have defined a scalar product

```
Clear[int]; int[a_, b_] := 
 Integrate[ a b  Pdf1, Sequence @@ rg // Evaluate]
```

and a numerical integration version of it

```
 Clear[nint]; nint[a_, b_] := 
 NIntegrate[ a b  Pdf1, Sequence @@ rg // Evaluate]
```

I define my 2D polynomial

```
p = 2; pol0 = 
 Table[Table[x1^i x2^(p1 - i), {i, 0, p1}] // Flatten // Union,
    {p1, 0, p}] // Flatten // Join
```

{1, x1, x2, x1^2, x1 x2, x2}

```
 pol = Orthogonalize[pol0, int[#1, #2] &]
```

They look like this:

```
Map[ContourPlot[# Pdf1  , Sequence @@ rgn // Evaluate, 
   PlotPoints -> 15, PlotRange -> All] &, pol]
```

[image]

If I do the same thing numerically

```
 pol = Orthogonalize[pol0, intn[#1, #2] &,  Method -> "Reorthogonalization"];
```

I get the same answer.

**But**

If I try and find **higher order** polynomials numerically

```
 p = 6; pol0 = 
 Table[Table[x1^i x2^(p1 - i), {i, 0, p1}] // Flatten // Union,
    {p1, 0, p}] // Flatten // Join;
pol = Orthogonalize[pol0, intn[#1, #2] &,  Method -> "Reorthogonalization"];
```

I get this

(* {1.,1.81473 x1-0.804133,-1.53835 x1+2.37903 x2+1.73585,2.33148 x1^2-2.23663 x1+0.170409 x2-0.0991482,-2.84065 x1^2+4.36636 x1 x2+4.97902 x1-2.46156 x2-1.87669,1.84722 x1^2-5.47403 x1 x2-4.89841 x1+4.11307 x2^2+6.90647 x2+2.25076,0,3.15107 x1^2 x2+1.83935 x1^2-3.44839 x1 x2-3.23326 x1+0.212753 x2^2+0.21619 x2+0.676981,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} *)

In other words the *loss of accuracy* in the orthogonalisation leads to 
*zero* higher order polynomials.

---

I have also tried Gramm Schmitt by hand (from somewhere on SE)

```
gs[vecs_, ip___] := Module[{ovecs = vecs},
Do[ovecs[[i]] -= Projection[ovecs[[i]], ovecs[[j]], ip], {i, 2, 
Length[vecs]}, {j, 1, i - 1}]; ovecs]; 
pol1 = gs[pol0, Function[
    NIntegrate[ ##  Pdf1, Sequence @@ rg // Evaluate]]];
```

but it yields the same *loss of accuracy*.

---

I have also tried Eigenvectors of the matrix of scalar products

```
   mat = ParallelTable[int[i, j], {i, pol0}, {j, pol0}];
   eigs = Eigensystem[mat // N];
```

But the orthogonal polynomials are not of increasing order:

```
    Map[ContourPlot[#  Pdf1, Sequence @@ rgn // Evaluate, 
   PlotPoints -> 15, PlotRange -> All] &, 
 pol = eigs[[2]].pol0/Sqrt[eigs[[1]]] // Chop]
```

[image]

Note that while orthogonal they are not orthogonal 'in the same direction'.

**Question**

> How can I compute the higher order orthogonal polynomials *accurately*?

**Side Question**

One option would be to stick to symbolic evaluation of the scalar product,
but it seems to take forever for higher order polynomials.

> Is it possible to tell `Orthogonalize` to not Normalise the polynomials which symbolically seems to take longest?

Comment: May I ask why you try stick to a triangle? While [orthogonal polynomial bases on triangles](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09099) are known, it is much easier to deal with orthogonal polynomials on a square or a cube. Moreover, polynomials are not square-integrable over the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$ so Mathematica cannot compute the integrals correctly. I suggest to try (tensorproducts of) [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials), multiplied by $\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$; they are orthogonal right from the start.

Comment: Because I can always rank my 2 eigenvalues so that x1>x2 (?). These polynomials are square-integrable over ℝ2 here because of the Gaussian part of the PDF? I have used in the past Hermite like polynomials (e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.1863.pdf) but here I want to find the new polynomials for the Kernel of the eigenvalues. Or are you saying I should start with the Hermitte before orthogonalisation ?

Comment: Alternatively I could remove the `x1>x2` constraint but then my integrant would have `|x1-x2|` instead of `(x1-x2)`

Comment: Oh, I overlooked `Pdf1` in the integrand. Sorry. Towards the eigenvalues: Yes, you _can_ order them, but I tried to say that computations might be easier without doing so. Of course, you would have to replace `Pdf1` by the correct distribution on the whole $mathbb{R}^2$ (by multiplying by `1/2` and throwing in some `Abs`). This would allow you to use Hermite polynomials.

Comment: I just tried with this: `pol0 = Table[ 
    Table[HermiteH[i, x1] HermiteH[(p1 - i), x2], {i, 0, p1}] // 
      Flatten // Union,
    {p1, 0, p}] // Flatten // Join` and I get the same loss of accuracy.

Comment: Uh. I forgot that `Pdf1` is not the standard Gaussian, so the Hermite polynomials are not orthogonal with respect to it. =/ Hm. I am out of ideas for the moment.

Comment: Would you know how to make use of the eigenvectors of the matrix of scalar product to produce the same polynomials as GrammSchmitt? because this can be computed symbolically efficiently.

Comment: Have you tried adding a higher `WorkingPrecision->50` to your `NIntegrate` call in the definition of `nint`? This should help with the loss of accuracy.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke I didn't try 50 but I tried PrecisionGoal-> 10 and that took a long time so its not realistic since I am aiming for large p.

Comment: @chris: `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` are a bit different: If set to a low value they give `NIntegrate` a bail out option to stop early, but they don't change the number precision `NIntegrate` uses for intermediate values in the internal calculations. By default `NIntegrate` will use fast `$MachinePrecision` numbers to perform those calculations but this (double) precision might not be enough to prevent catastrophic cancellation for high order oscillating polynomials. `WorkingPrecision` tells Mma to use arbitrary precision numbers internally, which should solve the cancellation issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Eigensystem` is actually a great idea. The following should generate an orthonormal basis `basis`. Notice however that `NIntegrate` has its problems to compute the integrals accurately.

```
B = Threshold[Table[nint[a, b], {a, pol0}, {b, pol0}], 100 $MachineEpsilon];
{λ, U} = Eigensystem[B];
U = (U/Sqrt[λ]);
basis = U.pol0;
```

## Edit

Having the Gram matrix `B` already, `Orthogonalize` seems to work quite well:

```
basis = Orthogonalize[IdentityMatrix[Length[B]], #1.B.#2 &].pol0
```

> {1., -0.804133 + 1.81473 x1, 
>    1.73585 - 1.53835 x1 + 2.37903 x2, -0.0991483 - 2.23663 x1 + 
>     2.33148 x1^2 + 0.170409 x2, -1.87669 + 4.97902 x1 - 2.84065 x1^2 - 
>     2.46156 x2 + 4.36636 x1 x2, 
>    2.25076 - 4.89842 x1 + 1.84722 x1^2 + 6.90648 x2 - 5.47404 x1 x2 + 
>     4.11307 x2^2}

and for p=4
[image]

Comment: Thanks ! I think that's exactly what I need. It seems obvious retrospectively  as always :-)

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: It seems to me this could be an option of the Orthogonalize function? Its fairly efficient.

Comment: I have a supplementary pb. For large matrices (> 60x60), even if the matrix is known symbolically, the basis starts to show inaccuracies. I have tried N[#1.B.#2,40]& say but it does not seem to help. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: @chris Hm. I am actually clueless here. In fact, I haven't had time yet to wait for the Gram matrix `B` of size $60 \times 60$ to evaluate. It's clear that `nint` without further options will have very limited accuracy, but you say you computed `B` symbolically? That must have taken forever. But even with symbolic Gram matrix, I am not surprised that you will have accucary problems.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Symbolically its fairly fast thanks to this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189131/1089

Comment: Very ill-conditioned matrices are actually omnipresent wherever people work with polynomial bases; the real mastership in these arts is to be able to circumvent them. This is why precomputed bases such as Hermite polynomials are so important. Unfortunately, I am not an expert in this field (also because I was told early in classes on finite elements that high degree polynomial approximation is evil ;) ).

Comment: I use : `p = 11; pol0 = 
 Table[Table[HermiteH[i, x1] HermiteH[(p1 - i), x2], {i, 0, p1}] // 
      Flatten // Union,
    {p1, 0, p}] // Flatten // Join` (So Hermites as a starting point).

Comment: Then I compute the characteristic function: genF = Integrate[
  E^(I ((a + b) t1 + (a - b) t2))*2*4*b*
   E^(-2 (a^2 + 2 b^2)) Sqrt[
    2/\[Pi]], {a, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {b, 0, \[Infinity]}]

Comment: and then I compute the matrix: mat = Expand@
   Outer[Times, pol0, pol0] /. {x1^n_. x2^p_. :> 
    p! n! (-I)^(n + p) SeriesCoefficient[
      genF, {t1, 0, n}, {t2, 0, p}], 
   x1^n_. :> 
    n! (-I)^(n) SeriesCoefficient[genF, {t1, 0, n}, {t2, 0, 0}], 
   x2^p_. :> 
    p!  (-I)^(p) SeriesCoefficient[genF, {t1, 0, 0}, {t2, 0, p}]}

Comment: Its condition number is about 22. the matrix is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ywqltz0m01e3jsh/defmat.m?dl=1

Comment: But thanks I don't want to take more of your time... This pb turns out to be a pain at every corner :-)

Comment: @chris Indeed, I have only little time at the moment because I am on a journey. Maybe I find some more on the weekend. "Its condition number is about 22." Hm... that makes me curious.

Comment: I do mean cond = 10^22 right :-). Please don't waste your time I just wanted to know if you had a quick fix that's all.