# Characteristic Function of 2D Gaussian with Boole

Tags: probability-or-statistics, symbolic

**Context**

Given the    Probability Distribution

```
pdf=ProbabilityDistribution[2*(x1 - x2)*
  E^((-(x1*(3*x1 - x2)) - x2*(-x1 + 3*x2))/2)*
  Sqrt[2/Pi], {x1, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 {x2, -Infinity, x1}];
```

Note the Boundary on x2.

**Question**

> I would like to compute the Characteristic Function of this PDF.

**Attempt**

```
 CF=CharacteristicFunction[pdf, {y1, y2}]
```

seems to take forever before crashing  the kernel.

Note: these math.SE posts [link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2236490/32833) and [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/153421/32833) are of interest.

The purpose of knowing this Characteristic Function  is to compute symbolically the matrix 
of scalar products involved in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/187746/1089).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the substitutions $a=(x_1+x_2)/2$ and $b=(x_1-x_2)/2$, giving $x_1=a+b$ and $x_2=a-b$, the characteristic function $\langle e^{i(x_1t_1+x_2t_1)}\rangle$ is

```
Integrate[E^(I((a+b)t1+(a-b)t2)) * 2 *4*b*E^(-2(a^2+2b^2))Sqrt[2/π],
  {a, -∞, ∞}, {b, 0, ∞}]
```

which evaluates in a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should have thought about this. Its puzzling why Mathematica doesn't try such transformations though.