# Characteristic Function of 3D Gaussian with Boole

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics

**Context**

Given the    Probability Distribution

```
pdf=ProbabilityDistribution[(1/(8 π))675 Sqrt[5] *
  (x1-x2) (x1-x3) (x2-x3) 
Exp[1/2 (-x1 (6 x1-(3 x2)/2-(3 x3)/2)-x2 (-((3 x1)/2)+6 x2-(3 x3)/2)-
x3 (-((3 x1)/2)-(3 x2)/2+6 x3))],
 {x1,-∞,∞},{x2,-∞,x1},{x3,-∞,x2}]
```

Note the Boundary on x2 and x3.

**Question**

> I would like to compute the Characteristic Function of this PDF.

**Attempt**

```
 CF=CharacteristicFunction[pdf, {y1,y2,y3}]
```

takes forever.

I have tried rectifying the boundary as follows:

```
rs = Solve[{(x3 - x2)/2 == a, (x2 - x1)/2 == b, x3 == c}, {x1, x2, x3}][[1]];
  pdf2 = Exp[I x1 y1 + I x2 y2 + I x3 y3 ] PDF[pdf,{x1,x2,x3}] /. rs // Simplify
```

(* (-675*Sqrt[5]*a*b*(a + b)*
  E^(-18*a^2 - 12*b^2 - (9*c^2)/2 + 
    b*(6*c - (2*I)*y1) - 
    2*a*(9*b - 6*c + I*(y1 + y2)) + 
    I * c*(y1 + y2 + y3)))/π   *)

But this does not seem to converge either:

```
Integrate[pdf2 , {c, -∞, ∞}, {b, -∞,0}, {a, -∞, 0}]
```

runs forever.

I can integrate over 2 out of the 3 variables.

```
Integrate[pdf2 , {b, -∞, 0}, {c, -∞, ∞}]
```

but last integral also runs forever.

Any guidance would be welcome! :-)

Note: The purpose of knowing this Characteristic Function  is to compute symbolically the matrix 
of scalar products involved in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/187746/1089), but 
for 3D curvature.

Comment: You could ask the genius integrators over at https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Don't forget the factor of 4 coming from the Jacobian of your coordinate transformation. As `pdf2` stands now, its integral is equal to $1/4$ instead of 1. You can find the Jacobian with `D[{x1, x2, x3} /. rs, {{a, b, c}}] // Det // Abs`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion of this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189127/1089), the Characteristic function can be *partially* computed after the following change of variable  on the PDF:

```
rs = Solve[{(x3 - x2)/2 == a, (x2 - x1)/2 == b, x3 == c}, {x1, x2, x3}][[1]]
```

as

```
Pdf2 = Exp[I x1 y1 + I x2 y2 + I x3 y3 ] Pdf1 /. rs // Simplify
```

(* -((675 Sqrt[5] a b (a+b) exp(-18 a^2-2 a (9 b-6 c+I (y1+y2))-12 b^2+b (6 c-2 I y1)-(9 c^2)/2+I c (y1+y2+y3)))/π) *)

Then the first two integrals can be done.

```
CF2 = 4 Integrate[Pdf2 , {b, -Infinity, 0}, {c, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

[image]

The good news is that if you only want the moments (as it happens) they can still  be computed `exactly` as follows

```
Clear[mom]; 
mom[p1_, p2_, p3_] := 
 mom[p1, p2, p3] = 
   (1/I)^(p1 + p2 + p3) D[CF2, {y1, p1}, {y2, p2}, {y3, p3}] /. 
     Thread[{y1, y2, y3} -> 0] // 
    FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> a < 0] & // 
   Integrate[#, {a, -Infinity, 0}] &
```

FYI they involve quantities such as

```
4/375 (283 Sqrt[10/π]-32 Sqrt[30 π])
```